# Improperly Configured

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a https://dog.ceo/dog-api/ clone with Django Rest Framework. I got the error: "ImproperlyConfigured at /breeds/

Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "breedimage-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.", and I am not sure how to solve it.

Here is some of my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Breed(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=150)


      def __str__(self):
          return self.name

class BreedImage(models.Model):
    breed = models.ForeignKey(Breed, related_name='BreedImages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    breedImage = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
```

```
serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Breed, BreedImage

class BreedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    BreedImages = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='breedimage-detail', many=True, read_only=True, lookup_field='breed')

    class Meta:
        model = Breed
        fields = ['name', 'BreedImages']
```

```
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Breed
from .serializers import BreedSerializer
# Create your views here.


class BreedList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Breed.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BreedSerializer


class BreedDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Breed.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BreedSerializer
```

```
urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from Breed import views



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('breeds/', views.BreedList.as_view()),
    path('breeds/<name>', views.BreedDetail.as_view()),
]
```

I have followed this tutorial - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#example.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Update your urlpatterns, add `name="breedimage-detail"`,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('breeds/', views.BreedList.as_view()),
    path('breeds/<name>', views.BreedDetail.as_view(), name="breedimage-detail"), # here
]
```

Comment: I did that and i still have this problem.